# Get only relevant sub-category of category "Genre" that applies to current product only

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

As the title suggests, I am trying to get the sub-category of the Genre category.

**My WooCommerce category structure looks like this for example**:

`Genre, Genre > Rock, Artist, Artist > Abigail Jay > Hulking Depend Weigh, Album > Hulking Depend Weigh, Year, Year > 2014`

I know what my product/song ID is.
I know what the Genre category ID is.

I struggle with the following:

```
global $product;
$terms = get_the_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_cat');
foreach($terms as $term)
{
    if($term->slug == "genre")
    {
        $_id = $term->term_id;
        $_s = $term->slug;
        $_ar = array('parent' => $_id);
        $assoc_categories = get_terms('product_cat', $_ar);
    }
}
```

When running `print_r($assoc_categories);` of the above, it simply returns an array with all the sub-categories of parent "Genre". This is however not right as I need to get the name of only the relevant sub-category associated with the specific product/song.

Say for example, the genre of the song is "Rock". Rock is a sub-category of the "Genre" category. The sub-category Rock is associated with the product/song name.

How can I access only the relevant sub-category of Genre in this instance?

I am struggling a bit to find answers online, unless I keep looking for the wrong solution, by searching the wrong terms...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Please do keep in mind that I am still learning about coding with WordPress**

Answer (score 0):

For more info, check this thread over on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894671/).

To answer my own question, I have created a more comprehensive bit of code that builds an array containing the following:

- Artist Name, ID, Slug >

  - Each Albums Name, ID, Slug, Year, Genre >

    - Each Songs Name, ID, Slug, SKU, Link to a preview of the Track

```php
if((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)
{
    $GLOBALS['base_href'] = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/';
}
else
{
    $GLOBALS['base_href'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/';
} // END OF: if((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'...
$main_category = get_queried_object();
$main_category_id = $main_category->term_id;
$main_category_name = $main_category->name;
$main_category_slug = $main_category->slug;
foreach(get_terms('product_cat',  $main_category_id) as $term)
{
    if($term->slug == "genre")
    {
        foreach(get_terms('product_cat', ['parent' => $term->term_id]) as $_gt)
        {
            $genre_dict[] = $_gt->name;
        }
    } // END OF: if($term->slug == "genre"...
    if($term->slug == "year")
    {
        foreach(get_terms('product_cat', ['parent' => $term->term_id]) as $_gt)
        {
            $year_dict[] = $_gt->name;
        }
    } // END OF: if($term->slug == "year"...
} // END OF: foreach(get_terms('product_cat',  $sub_category_id...

$_ARTIST_OBJ = 
[
    'artist_id' => $main_category->term_id,
    'artist_name' => $main_category->name,
    'artist_slug' => $main_category->slug
];
foreach(get_terms('product_cat', ['parent' => $main_category_id]) as $sub_category)
{
    
    $sub_category_id = $sub_category->term_id;
    $sub_category_name = $sub_category->name;
    $sub_category_slug = $sub_category->slug;

    $_ARTIST_OBJ['artist_albums'][$sub_category->slug] = 
    [
        'album_id' => $sub_category->term_id,
        'album_name' => $sub_category->name,
        'album_slug' => $sub_category->slug,
        'album_year' => "",
        'album_genre' => "",
        'album_artwork' => $GLOBALS['base_href'].'wp-content/uploads/album_images/'.$sub_category->slug.'.jpg',
        'album_tracks' => []
    ];

    $product_loop = new WP_Query
    (
        [
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'product_cat' => $sub_category_name,
            'field' => $sub_category_id
        ]
    );
    if($product_loop->have_posts())
    {
        while($product_loop->have_posts())
        {
            $product_loop->the_post();
            global $product;
            $_ARTIST_OBJ['artist_albums'][$sub_category->slug]['album_tracks'][$product->get_slug()] = 
            [
                'track_id' => $product->get_id(),
                'track_name' => $product->get_name(),
                'track_slug' => $product->get_slug(),
                'track_sku' => $product->get_sku(),
                'track_preview' => $GLOBALS['base_href'].'wp-content/uploads/audio/samples/'.strtolower(str_replace(array(" ", "-"), "", $product->get_name().$product->get_sku())).'-sample.mp3'
            ];
            foreach(get_the_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_cat') as $term)
            {
                if(in_array($term->name, $genre_dict))
                {
                    $_ARTIST_OBJ['artist_albums'][$sub_category->slug]['album_genre'] = $term->name;
                } // END OF: if(in_array($term->name, $genre_dict...
                if(in_array($term->name, $year_dict))
                {
                    $_ARTIST_OBJ['artist_albums'][$sub_category->slug]['album_year'] = $term->name;
                } // END OF: if(in_array($term->name, $year_dict...
                
            }

        } // END OF: while($product_loop->have_posts(...
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<p>There are not products...</p>");
    } // END OF: if($product_loop->have_posts(...
} // END OF: foreach(get_terms('product_cat', ['parent' => $main_category_id...

print_r($_ARTIST_OBJ);
```

Hopefully this may help another Noob that comes across the same challenge somewhere down the line.